# Use pre-allocated cuda memory pointer to initialize an opencv GpuMat in python

Tags: python, opencv, pycuda

Is there a way to use a memory pointer that has already been allocated to create a GpuMat in OpenCV python?

There is the C++ definition for `GpuMat()` which takes `void* data` as input.

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat    (   Size    size,
int     type,
void *  data,
size_t  step = Mat::AUTO_STEP 
)   

cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat    (   int     rows,
int     cols,
int     type,
void *  data,
size_t  step = Mat::AUTO_STEP 
)
```

There are no equivalent python bindings for these definitions in OpenCV, so this option does not work in Python.

I have a PyCuda array which is already created. So, I can access the Cuda pointer of that array. Could we use the existing pointer in Python to create a `GpuMat` without having to download the data back to the host memory, and upload it again?

Looking at the `GpuMat` class in Python, I do not see a way to access the `cudaPtr` or `data` variables of the `GpuMat` class to allocate something using the `defaultAllocator` interface.